# CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR - getSession in API Route returns null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, session, next.js, next-auth

I want to get session data in my API Route to use it in prisma find() but function always returns `null` and i receive an error:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I tried everything and still nothing. Also in my production i have another error when I want to log in: `signin?error=Callback` - `Try signing in with a different account`.

Ofc. in .env I have:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000
```

My `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file looks like:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,

      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  },
  useSecureCookies: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
});
```

and my get file in api:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { prisma } from "../../../app/prisma";

export default async function handle(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const session = await getSession({ req });

  const result = {
    session,
  };

  res.json(result);
}
```

and result is always null.